# Show only selected filters on active admin index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Is it possible to show only listed filter and not all default filters like all associations filters in active admin.

I have to manually skip the filters using
`remove_filter :groups` etc
And whenever add any association it comes on the page automatically which i want to disable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If explicitly use `filter :attribute` keyword, it will display only this filter, not default ones.

Comment: Thanks I searched a lot for specific but din got that, but how to add custom filter was given which is the same i guess.